# dynamic size limit for multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i have a multer middleware like this.I have a setting table which has upload size limit in it. get size limit is an async function which gets data from this model. but icant use it in multer filesize. beacuse it needs await behind it.
what can i do?
i want to set limit size in setting

```
const multer = require("multer");
const SettingModel = require("../../models/Setting");
const SequelizeService = require("../app/sequelize/sequelize.service");
let Setting = new SequelizeService(SettingModel);

async function getSizeLimit() {
  let setting = await Setting.findOne({ raw: true });
  return 1024 * 1024 * setting.sizeLimit;
}
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, ""));
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // let response = new Response();
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/webp"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("Not an image! Please upload an image.", 400), false);
  }
};

exports.upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: getSizeLimit(),
  },

  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it by caching my setting and changing my middleware to :

```js
let multer = require("multer");
const cache = require("memory-cache");

upload_image = function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let limit = cache.get("sizeLimit");
    let upload = multer({
      storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, "./uploads/");
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, ""));
        },
      }),
      limits: {
        fileSize: limit * 1024 * 1024,
      },
      onError: function (err, next) {
        next(err);
      },
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (
          file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" ||
          file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
          file.mimetype === "image/webp"
        ) {
          cb(null, true);
        } else {
          cb(new Error("Not an image! Please upload an image.", 400), false);
        }
      },
    });

    upload.single("photo")(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      }
      next();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};

exports.upload_image = upload_image;
```